# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on DX DevHub trial org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, dev-hub

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I signed up for a DevHub trial org, got the verification email, clicked the verify link and immediately got a

> This site can’t be reached
>
> [domain].my.salesforce.com refused to connect.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tried multiple browsers, multiple networks, no firewall or proxy settings at all. Thoughts?

Comment: I've had that happen a few times. (Last week in fact at TrailheaDX...) At least in my case, if I wait a little while and try again, it usually works. It's like they send the email early before the DevHub is done generating.

Comment: @Genko Perhaps that was the case, it did eventually work... Thanks.